# Dealing with slow publisher in project reactor concatMap

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I've below code which programmatically generates Flux using generate. Since the result is `Flux<Mono<T>>` I'm using concatMap to map result to `Flux<T>`. The producer of `Mono<T>` works based on throttling. If too many requests are sent in short period of time it results in exception. To deal with this I've provided a subscriber that calls request(n) in `hookOnSubscribe()` and `hookOnNext()`. I want remote API to be called only request(n) times. This is like pull based request. But concatMap request upstream publisher even when there is no demand from downstream and it results in throttling exception. How can I make sure that remote API is called only `request(n)` times?

```
Flux<Mono<Result>> generate = Flux.generate(
                () -> queryRequest,
                (state, sink) -> {
                    if(!state.isPrepared() || !state.isDone()) {
                        Mono<Result> nextPage = execute(state).doOnNext(result -> {
                            QueryResult result1 = (QueryResult) result;
                            state.setContKey(result1.getContinuationKey());
                        });
                        sink.next(nextPage);
                    } else {
                        sink.complete();
                    }
                    return state;
                }
        );
       generate.concatMap(resultMono -> resultMono);
```